# Jquery, Cannot get the each li in Div

Tags: jquery

I have multiple `<div class='ms-drop'>` with many `<li>` items inside them. I am trying reach each `<li>` item.

I was trying several ways, this is what I got:

```
 $(function() {
       var counter = 0;
        $('.ms-drop').each(function() { // loop each div
            counter++;
            $(this).attr('id','ms-drop-' + counter); // here I am giving each div a it's own id > $(this) did not work!
            var id = $(this).attr('id');

            $('#ms-drop-' + id + ' il').each(function() {
                console.log("li"); // it does not reach here !
            });                        
        });
 });
```

**HtML**

```
<div class="ms-drop bottom" style="display: block;">
     <ul style="max-height: 250px;">           
        <li class=" " style="false"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItem" value="60"><span>ABC</span></label></li>
        <li class=" " style="false"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItem" value="38"><span>DEF</span></label></li>
        <li class=" " style="false"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItem" value="45"><span>GHI</span></label></li>
        <li class=" " style="false"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItem" value="2863"><span>JKL</span></label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

ABC
            DEF
            GHI
            JKL

Comment: is it a typo in your code that you have `il` instead of `li`?

Comment: instead of your `$('#ms-drop-' + id + ' li')` (typo corrected) you could do `$(this).find('li')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to target `<il>` elements instead of `<li>` elements within your function on account of a likely typo. Simply change the `il` to `li` and it should target the appropriate child `<li>` elements as seen below :

```
$('#ms-drop-' + id + ' li').each(function(){
      console.log("li");
});
```

Another issue here is that when you are actually setting your ID attribute and then appending that same value to "#ms-drop-" within your selector :

```
// This sets your ID to 'ms-drop-{counter}'
$(this).attr('id','ms-drop-' + counter);
// Now when you reference this, you'll get '#ms-drop-ms-drop-{counter} li'
$('#ms-drop-' + id + ' li').each(function(){ ... });
```

An easier approach since you already have the element in context, would simply be to use [jQuery's context selector](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context) to target all of the `li` elements beneath your current "drop" :

```
$(this).attr('id','ms-drop-' + counter);
// Now when you reference this, you'll get '#ms-drop-ms-drop-{counter} li'
$('li',this).each(function(){ ... });
```

You could also consider using the [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) function as well, which would work similarly :

```
$(this).find('li').each(function(){ ... });
```

**Example**

```js
$(function() {
        var counter = 0;
        $('.ms-drop').each(function() {
            // Increment your counter
            counter++;
            // Set your ID
            $(this).attr('id','ms-drop-' + counter);
            $('li',this).each(function() {
                // Output the text (for example purposes)
                console.log($(this).text().trim()); 
            });                        
        });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ms-drop bottom" style="display: block;">
  <ul style="max-height: 250px;">
    <li class=" " style="false">
      <label class="">
        <input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItem" value="60"><span>ABC</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class=" " style="false">
      <label class="">
        <input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItem" value="38"><span>DEF</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class=" " style="false">
      <label class="">
        <input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItem" value="45"><span>GHI</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class=" " style="false">
      <label class="">
        <input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItem" value="2863"><span>JKL</span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `console.log`-part, because I don't understand why you want to look up for them, when you aren't finished to create them.

```
$(function() {
       var counter = 0;
        $('.ms-drop ul li').each(function() { // loop each div
            counter++;
            $(this).attr('id','ms-drop-' + counter); // here I am giving each div a it's own id > $(this) did not work!
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use 'find()' to get array of li elements within each div.

`$(function() {
       var counter = 0;
        $('.ms-drop').each(function() { // loop each div
            $(this).find('li').each(function(liElement){
                console.log(liElement);
            });

        });
 });`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is perhaps a working version of your code:

```
$(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    $('.ms-drop').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('id','ms-drop-'+(counter++))
               .find('li')
               .each(function() {
                   console.log("li");
               });
    });
});
```